# Echo a string literal from PHP that includes both quotes and apostrophes

Tags: php, html, web

I have a little bit more complicated row than I can handle.

I am echoing and I got lost in the " ', could someone help me out and tell me how to have this line correctly?

```
echo '<td style="text-align: center"><a onclick=" window.open('/edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . ','_self')"><img height="30" width="30" src="/wp-content/themes/sparkling/edit.png"/></a></td>';
```

Comment: Or [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: It is called "escaping", I suggest you Google that for a bit. It's not difficult, and give you some useful insights.

Comment: Martin, consider using intermediate variables because code like this has quite bad legibility. Start from the middle, append the next part, put it into a named constant and repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape single quotation?

```
echo '...<a onclick=" window.open(\'/edit.php?id=...';
```

**Edit**

To show single quotation in string wrapped with single quotation, you need to ***escape*** it, like this

```
echo 'Hello \' world';
```

So your code should be

```
echo '<td style="text-align: center"><a onclick=" window.open(\'/edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '\',\'_self\')"><img height="30" width="30" src="/wp-content/themes/sparkling/edit.png"/></a></td>';
```

Comment: no. I need a third kind of quotations if that is possible?

Comment: You mean wrap it in different quotation?

Comment: possibly. When I quote as I posted I get an error. And I do not understand your answer. If you could rewrite it for me (the whole line) that would be great.

Comment: Perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc ?

Comment: Andreas..Not helpful.

Comment: Ok... It's a third way to enclose strings as you asked for. See example: https://3v4l.org/SJTBO

Comment: @MartinŠvejda what this answer is doing: add a \ (backslash) before every occurrence of `'` inside your string (not the first and last one). This will solve your problem

Comment: @MartinŠvejda Updated the answer. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, but somehow it doesnt work..I dont have that image clickable

Comment: @MartinŠvejda Ah I forgot to close another quotation, updated the answer

Comment: Yes thank you that works. And one more question...When I point my cursor on the image, I do not get a sign that it is clickable. How do I set that the cursor changes as it shoud be when the image is clickable..hope you underestand

Comment: You have 2 option: add `href="#"` or CSS [`cursor`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) property

Answer (score 0):

Use the heredoc syntax to create the string and your `"` and `'` can be used freely inside the string.
See manual about heredoc http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Example of heredoc:
https://3v4l.org/SJTBO

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a third quotation mark in code.
But, using "heredoc" syntax is really usefull when you want/need to keep both the single and double quotes unescaped.
Using it, your code should look like this:

```
echo <<<EOD
<td style="text-align: center">
  <a onclick="window.open('/edit.php?id='{$row['id']}', '_self')">
    <img height="30" width="30" src="/wp-content/themes/sparkling/edit.png"/>
  </a>
</td>
EOD;
```

Think about using `{ }` around your variables to make them more visible.

See documentation about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc